# How to extract href links for the footer when it overlapping the page using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how to extract data when the page overlaps with the advertisement.
example1:https://www.glowandlovelycareers.in/en/

I want to extract cookie policy and privacy policy links in the footer

similar problem for other websites even code to be dynamic to satisfies for other websites.

sleep.time(3) required for the banner to appear, mean while advertising popup also apperance. source code takes only pop up data.

example 2: https://presence.tresemme.com/uk/login
logic page restricting to extract the footer data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import os
import sys    
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import unidecode
import json

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False) 


driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=cap, firefox_profile=fp)

currenturl = 'https://www.glowandlovelycareers.in/en/'
r = requests.get(currenturl)
 
# soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

time.sleep(3) # time to display banner 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
footer =  soup.findAll('div', class_=re.compile('footer-wrapper'))
print("FOOTER", footer)

for a in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("www.unilevernotices.com", re.IGNORECASE)}):
    print(a)


time.sleep(4)
driver.close()
```

Comment: This should be `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")` after banner display if you are using selenium.

Comment: not right solution however, it's good for privacy link extraction but cookie links present in banner and footer ( print(soup) print all the data including banners) I want particularly footer extractions